# Is this a fused relative?

Tags: free-relative-clauses

> "I couldn't help overhearing what you and Malfoy were saying ––" 
>       "Bet you could," Ron muttered. 
>       "––and you mustn't go wandering around the school at night, think of the points you'll lose Gryffindor if you're caught, and you're
>   bound to be. It's really very selfish of you." 
>       "And it's really none of your business," said Harry. 
>       "Good-bye," said Ron. 
>        All the same, it wasn't **what you'd call the perfect end to the day**, Harry thought, **as** he lay awake much later listening to Dean
>   and Seamus falling asleep (Neville wasn't back from the hospital
>   wing).
>
> –– Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

[i] Is the highlighted part a fused relative (or free relative)? 
I guess *what* in ‘what you’d call Ø the perfect end to the day’ is a fused relative. But there being a dummy it, I’m not sure.

[ii] Is ‘as’ a conjunction for saying the reason of aforesaid words?

[iii] Is 'to the day' an idiom, meaning '[exactly](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/to+the+day#day__236)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[i] The clause is indeed a free relative, but *it* here is not a dummy but an ordinary pronoun: its antecedent is the events which have just been narrated. This is clear from the fact that ...

[ii] Harry thinks this *as* he is lying in bed, just after the waking ‘day’ has ended. *As* here bears the temporal sense = *while*.

[iii] With *end* or *start*, *to* has approximately the same meaning as *of*; its use in place of *of* gives a little extra sense of impetus at the beginning and closure at the end.

The passage may be very loosely paraphrased:

> Lying in bed, still awake, Harry looked back on what had just happened and found it a very unsatisfactory end of the day.